# Highcharts behaviour in mobile browser (scrolling the whole graph not the specific point)

Tags: scroll, highcharts, titanium-mobile, touch-event

I am using highcharts in my app and it has a problem which is: when I scroll the pointer to point in a different place in the chart the whole chart is scrolled while the point still in its position.

For more explanation please try this link in browser and mobile:
http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

I just need the mobile behave as the browser behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable panning and pinchType.

```
chart: {
            panning: false,
            pinchType: false
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bL4bqcLv/3/